# Where does NetBeans create Derby Embeded DB

Tags: netbeans, derby

I have created a Derby Embeded DB in netbeans. Now I can not find the folder in which DB is placed by netbeans.
My connection URL is `jdbc:derby:Inventory;create=true;`.
Where does netbeans place the DB file by default?
I am using Ubuntu 12.04.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Default Linux Netbeans Database Folder :

```
/home/username/.netbeans-derby/
```

there is a folder `Inventory`

netbeans 7.2.1 :

```
/home/username/.netbeans/7.2.1/derby/
```

you can search with

```
sudo find / -name Inventory -print
```

**Properties :**

right click `Java DB` select Create Database.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was not in .netbeans-derby but in `/home/tariq/.netbeans/7.2.1/derby/Inventory` please post it with this directory and I will mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

The database name "Inventory" is a relative name, so it will be located in the "Inventory" subdirectory of the Derby home directory. The Derby home directory defaults to the current working directory when your program runs. So you just have to figure out where the current working directory is when your program runs.

However, this is rather the hard way to go about things. Instead, change your connection URL so that it specifies an absolute name, such as

```
jdbc:derby:/home/tariq/myDerbyDBs/Inventory
```

and then you will easily be able to find your database. (Make sure that you create the '/home/tariq/myDerbyDBs' directory first.)

Comment: Current working directory means the directory where projects netbeans execute? or where my JRE exists? or where the Derby jre file exists? in all cases I can't find my DB.

Comment: I think absolute URLs are a poor practice. This ties the application to a database in _a very specific location_. What if, for example, someone else were to clone the source code and they don't have the user name 'tariq'? What if, for example, someone simple wants to run the application and they don't have the same user name? Even during testing/developing I would maintain this is poor practice. The answer is to understand where in an embedded Derby it puts the databases by default: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.14/devguide/cdevdvlp846369.html

Comment: OK, @Kerry, I think that is a good point. As long as you know where your current working directory is, relative file paths are fine. The original question involved a user who was confused about what the current working directory was, and had to run a `find` command to figure out where their database went. By the way, I am pleased you have read the documentation!